# Grid treaversal with forbidden coordinates

Tags: algorithms, square-grid

What alorithm/heuristic can be applied to get a shortest path to all the blue coordinates below without going through red coordinates? starting and ending in bottom left(0,0).

I have list of all the blue and red coordinates.

[image: Grid to be treaversed]